# Sorting a list of mixed integers and strings

Tags: c#, sorting, alphanumeric

I have a list with data that contains mixed numbers and strings, when i sort using

```
var list = thelist.OrderBy(p=>p.ColumnWithValues)
```

I would get results in the following order:

```
> 1, 1 item, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, a, another 1, b
```

But i want them to be in the order below:

```
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 1 item,a, another 1, b
```

How would I go about doing this? I'm not even sure what to try with a list of multiple properties

**update:**

I've fixed my sample data, is what i'm looking to do possible?

Comment: From where "another 1" came from?

Comment: And why does `1 item` disappear from the required output?

Comment: @Matthew It's called a magic sort

Answer (score 3):

You should sort by type first :

```
var list = thelist.OrderBy(p=> p.GetType() == typeof(string)).ThenBy(p => p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also try this.

```
var thelist = new[] {"1", "item", "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "a", "b", "c"};
        var list = thelist.Where( num => num.All( x => char.IsDigit( x ) ) )
                  .OrderBy( r => { int z; int.TryParse( r, out z ); return z; } )
                  .Union( thelist.Where( str => str.All( x => !char.IsDigit( x ) ) )
                  .OrderBy( q => q ) );

         foreach (var i in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());

            }
```

And here is the [.net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/S8saLa) to check...

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by writing a class containing using `IComparer`

implemented by using:

```
thelist.OrderBy(p => p.ColumnWithValues, new OrdinalStringComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = thelist.OrderBy(p=> p.GetType() == typeof(string)).ThenBy(p => p)
```

Above is exactly working for me.

```
Actual list = { "(unknown)", "(unknown)", "(unknown)", 
                "183", "so", "Mo", "170", "Opps" , "(unknown)" }
Expected list = { "(unknown)", "(unknown)", "(unknown)", 
                  "(unknown)", "170","183", "Mo" ,"Opps", "so" }
```